# User.businessPhones Property multi-valued?

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

According to the [Microsoft.Graph client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph), the BusinessPhones property is an array of strings. However, when trying to send a patch containing more then one value ...

```
{
  "businessPhones": [
    "+49 3514457x78",
    "+49 3514457x77"
  ],
}
```

... I get the following error ...

```
"error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid value specified for property 'businessPhones' of resource 'User'.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "...",
        "date": "..."
    }
}
```

When looking at the Azure AD management portal, the first value can be found on the "Work Info" tab in the "Office phone" field which also only takes one value. In the [Azure AD Graph API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) the value in "Office phone" as populated by setting the User.TelephoneNumber property, which was a single string.

So my question is... Is it intended, that the field is exposed as an array and if yes, what is the correct way of setting multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intended that the businessPhones property is exposed as a collection, but we currently only support singleton values. We plan to support values with multiple phone numbers in the future and wanted the type of that property to reflect that in order to avoid a breaking schema change in the future.

Comment: 3 years later, and this error still exists. Why is that not included in the documentation? That multi values are not yet supported ...

Comment: 7 years and counting...